# Trigger an event each time an item scrolls into viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have some items on a page. When they scroll into view, I add animation classes to them, like this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop(),
        bottomOfWindow = topOfWindow + $(window).height();

    $('.buckle').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                $(this).addClass('animate');
        }


    });

   });
```

[Here's a stripped-down JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2LPmr/)

This triggers the animation to occur one time per page load: when the image is 400px from the top of the viewport, the class gets added, the animation rolls, then the image remains static.

But now they are meant to animate once each time they scroll into the viewport, whether the user is scrolling upwards or downwards. In the case of the demo, the "Buckle" element would lose the class .animate after scrolling out of view, and have it re-applied when scrolling back in to view.

What would be the most efficient approach for triggering this with JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I entirely understood you, but I think its not a very good idea to trigger the animation `400px` from the top. What if the window/viewport's height is even less than `400px`, the animation would be initiated before it was scrolled into view. I think it should be determined via the windows bottom.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop(),
        bottomOfWindow = topOfWindow + $(window).height();

    $('.buckle').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        if(imagePos <= bottomOfWindow && imagePos >= topOfWindow){
            $(this).addClass('animate');
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('animate');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2LPmr/1/

Cheers!

Comment: I think it's also nice to let the user see more of the animation by adding some padding on the condition: `if(imagePos + 80 <= bottomOfWindow && imagePos - 80 >= topOfWindow){`. http://jsfiddle.net/2LPmr/2/